# Need to query the number of records for 2 child objects

Tags: apex, soql

There is a parent object say Parent__c and then 2 child objects (Child1__c and Child2__C) both with master-detail relationships to the parent.

1. What is the best way to query to get the all the Parent__c records that have more than one Child1__c records tied to Parent__c AND only one Child2__c record tied to Parent__c.

Appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't something that can be done with a single SOQL query and nothing else (though it could be done with two).

The easiest approach here is probably to take advantage of those master-detail relationships and create 2 rollup summary fields on the parent (to get the count of records for both child objects).

From there, it'd be a simple query because you'd be able to put those exact conditions (count1 > 1, count2 = 1) into the `WHERE` clause.

If you choose to take an approach that doesn't involve rollup summary fields, then you'd need to use Apex to process the query results to get the information you're looking for.

Comment: The way you phrased this it seems that the rollup query does not result in the final requirement, but it does.

Comment: @PhilW I've adjusted the phrasing a bit.